# How to enumerate through NSArray of NSDictionaries with a block call inside the loop?

Tags: ios, nsarray, uitableview, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

I get an self.usersArray with 2 elements in the format:

```
(
  {
  userCreated = "2012-01-05 12:27:22";
  username = Simulator;
  },
  {
  userCreated = "2013-01-01 14:27:22";
  username = "joey ";
  }
)
```

This is gotten in a completion block after which I call another method to fetch points for these 2 users through a helper class:

```
-(void)getPoints{
    self.usersPointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *usersDictionary in self.usersArray) {
        [SantiappsHelper fetchPointsForUser:[usersDictionary objectForKey:@"username"] WithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *points){
            if ([points count] > 0) {
                [self.usersPointsArray addObject:[points objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
        NSLog(@"self.usersPointsArray %@", self.usersPointsArray);
        }];
    }
}
```

The final self.usersPointsArray log looks like:

```
(
        {
        PUNTOS = 5;
        username = Simulator;
    },
        {
        PUNTOS = 2;
        username = joey;
    }
)
```

But the problem is that the way the call for points is structured, the self.usersPointsArray is returned twice, each time with an additional object, due to the for loop, I know.

Here is the Helper class method:

```
+(void)fetchPointsForUser:(NSString*)usuario WithCompletionHandler:(Handler2)handler{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/myapp/readpoints.php"];
    NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:usuario, @"userNa", nil];

    NSData *postData = [self encodeDictionary:postDict];

    // Create the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    __block NSArray *pointsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Peform the request
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                                 error:&error];
        if (error) {
            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %d %@", httpResponse.statusCode, error);
                return;
            }
            return;
        }

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        pointsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

        if (handler)
            handler(pointsArray);
    }); 

}
```

I cannot use the self.usersPointsArray with the initial objects, only with the finalized object.  It wont always be 2 elements, i actually dont know how many it will be.

What would be the way to structure it so I get a final call when the self.usersPointsArray is complete and then I reload my tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of your problem as a standard consumer-producer problem.  You can create a queue count for the amount of items that will be processed (int totalToProcess=self.usersArray.count).  Each time the completion handler is hit, it will do totalToProcess--.  When totalToProcess reaches 0 you have processed all of the elements in your queue and can refresh your table.

If I understand your question correctly I believe this solves your problem.  If not, hopefully I can with a bit more information.